# Java/Scala Required: Iterable[_ <: Float], found: Iterable[Float]

Tags: java, scala

I have a protobuf method in Java with definition

```
public Builder addAllTensor(
          Iterable<? extends Float> values)
```

I call the method in Scala with a `val a: ArrayList[Float]`, its ok during code check, but error during build

```
type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.ArrayList[scala.Float]
 required: Iterable[_ <: java.lang.Float]
```

But calling it with `a.toIterable` it raises error in code check(in IntelliJ IDEA)

```
Required: Iterable[_ <: Float], found: Iterable[Float]
```

(How could this be type mismatch...)
Just wonder why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `scala.Float` versus Java's `Float`.

Automatic conversion doesn't happen inside collections, you have to create somehow a collection of Java's `Float`.

*(EDIT)* More context (thanks @Suma): Scala's `Float` corresponds to Java's `float`, and Java containers can contain only `Float`, not `float`, because in Java primitives need to be boxed to participate in generics.

Comment: You might want to describe a difference between `float` and `Float` in Java (boxing) so that one understands why is `java.lang.Float` used in the first place.

Comment: Yes..Finally I use `java.lang.Float`.

Comment: @Suma I'm not sure to see how it's relevant here, if you want to add anything please do (or post a comment and I'll add it in the answer)

Comment: I think it might be worth mentioning the background: Scala `Float` corresponds to Java `float`, and Java containers can contain only `Float`, not `float`, because in Java primitives need to be boxed to participate in generics.